# Convergence of the integral $\int_0^1 \frac {1}{x\sqrt {1+x^\beta}}dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, improper-integrals

**Is my integral-convergence contradiction proof valid?**

I have to brush up on my proof making. I am a little rusty.
I was not sure if the following really held up.

I wanted to prove the following is convergent/divergent (working with improper fractions) $\beta \in $ Real numbers:

$$\int_{0}^1 \frac {1}{x\sqrt {1+x^\beta}}dx$$

The following is my thought process.

> The 'improper' aspect happens at 0, thus the root is of no concern which means $\beta$ can be any real number.
> If I am to solve this, I would use the Ratio convergence test. $\frac 1x$ is a similar function at $x\to0^+$.

I recognize, the following sounded iffy to me.

> I will attempt to prove it by contradiction. In the next steps I will use the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).
>
> Let's suppose $\int_{0^+}^1 \frac {1}{x\sqrt {1+x^\beta}}dx$ converges.
>
> If $\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\frac1x}{\frac1{x\sqrt {1+x^\beta}}} $=L where L$\in$Reals excluding $0$ Then $\int_{o^+}^1 \frac1x dx $ converges since their ratio is the same.
>
> But wait! Therein lies a contradiction, $\int_{o^+}^1 \frac1x dx $ does not converge! My original supposition fails. And if the original function is not convergent, then it is divergent by definition.

I welcome other ways to do it, I really am just curious and looking to better myself.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1+x^k}} ~=~ -\frac2k~\text{arctanh}~\sqrt{1+x^k}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not correct.

The integrand is continuous on $(0,1]$, thus potential problems are as $x \to 0^+$.

I would distinguish three cases.

- $\beta=0$. As $x \to 0^+$, $$ \frac {1}{x\sqrt {1+x^\beta}}
     \sim\frac {1}{\sqrt {2}} \frac1x$$ the initial integral is **divergent** in this case.
- $\beta>0$. As $x \to 0^+$, $$ \frac {1}{x \sqrt{1+x^\beta}}
     \sim\frac1x$$ the initial integral is **divergent** in this case.
- $\beta<0$. As $x \to 0^+$, $$ \frac {1}{x\sqrt {1+x^\beta}}=\frac {1}{x^{1-|\beta|/2}\sqrt {1+x^{|\beta|}}}
     \sim\frac1{x^{1-|\beta|/2}}$$ the initial integral is **convergent** in this case.